# Sublime Text 3 showing no output when using .split() method

Tags: python, split, sublimetext3

I am using `.split()` method on an input and sublime text just doesn't give an output, the file no more shows any output of any type, its like the file is corrupted. The code which i used:

```
x=input().split(',')
print(x)
```

I've tried the same line of codes in python idle and it works totally fine.

```
x=input().split(',')
print(x)
```

I expect the output of the input: `hello,hi,world` to be `['hello','hi','world']`
but it shows no output at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in code runner in Sublime Text does not support user inputs through its console. I would recommend using your Terminal to execute the code, or use [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL)